# How to change meta tag "twitter:description" for home page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, seo, meta-tags

I want to add/edit meta tag keyword and descriptions as per my need.

Currently meta tag "twitter:description" is showing short description but I want to add some other content as per my conditions, so please share my path where I can edit these meta tags.

Also, I want to add meta tag "og:image" and URL will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

you can add/edit meta tags from the controller by doing following.

1) Go to your controller file

```
namespace Vendor\Frontendsample\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action {

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
    Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set("Title");
        $resultPage->getConfig()->setDescription("Description");
        $resultPage->getConfig()->setKeywords("Key Words");

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: please accept answer if your problem solved